# How to insert dummy rows from SQL query

Tags: sql

I am inserting rows into blank table from another table. I am inserting rows from excel.

I have query from joining multiple tables and result is as below: Has below data example

Now I want to insert below data but adding missing dates records with dummy records

```
Date           Loc    count
01-01-2019     001    1
01-02-2019     001    4 
01-03-2019     001    7 
01-01-2019     002    2
```

Now i am looking for some query which fetch these data and additionally add dummy records for missing 2nd and 3rd days of January for location 2.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 0):

If all the dates and all the locations you want are somewhere in that table, you could use a cross join to produce all possible combinations and then left join the table to it to get the count if present for a combination.

```
SELECT x1.date,
       x2.loc,
       coalesce(t3.count, 0) count
       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
                    t1.date
                    FROM elbat t1) x1
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
                               t2.loc
                               FROM elbat loc) x2
            LEFT JOIN elbat t3
                      ON t3.date = x1.date
                         AND t3.loc = x2.loc;
```